# Table with overflow ignoring parent div

Tags: css, html-table, overflow

I have a problem with some CSS I am working on. I have a box, with padding of 10px on all sides, and a table inside. I want overflow: auto on the table, but when I scroll, the table ignores the top and bottom padding of it's parent depending on which way it's scrolling.

**CSS**

```
#infoHolder .bottom 
{
    width: 749px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#infoHolder .bottom table
{
    margin: 15px 0;
    width: 735px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
            <div id="infoHolder">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="7">
                                Info
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Info</td>
                        <td>Info</td>
                        <td>Info</td>
                        <td>Info</td>
                        <td>Info</td>
                        <td>Info</td>
                        <td>Info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Info</td>
                        <td>Info</td>
                        <td>Info</td>
                        <td>Info</td>
                        <td>Info</td>
                        <td>Info</td>
                        <td>Info</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

How can I make it so that the overflow takes the parent divs padding into account and not overlap with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal, so use margin instead of padding.

Or double wrap the table in an inner DIV.

Answer (score 0):

Thats normal behaviour, thee table will be rendered inside the div with 20px padding, this whole unit will then scroll, it doesnt make room after giving 20px padding and then scroll table inside that,

You can try something like: http://jsfiddle.net/mrVce/1/

```
    <div id="infoHolder">
        <div class="inner">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="7">
                        Info
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Info</td>
                <td>Info</td>
                <td>Info</td>
                <td>Info</td>
                <td>Info</td>
                <td>Info</td>
                <td>Info</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div>
```

```
#infoHolder
{
    width: 749px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background:yellow;
}
#infoHolder .inner{
height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
    border:1px solid green;
}        
#infoHolder table
{
    margin: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background:orange;
}
```